# open edx SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, django, openedx

I recently set up the e-commerce module, now I'm getting this error when I try to create a new course in e-commerce.

> Error! Failed to publish commerce data for
>   course-v1:organization+t101+2017 to LMS.

also, I'm getting this error log:

```
 - Failed to publish commerce data for [course-v1:Org1+CU1+2017] to LMS.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/ecommerce/ecommerce/ecommerce/courses/publishers.py", line 133, in publish
    response = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 120, in put
    return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/ecommerce/venvs/ecommerce/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
2018-11-14 13:56:34,049 ERROR 90986 [ecommerce.extensions.api.serializers] /edx/app/ecommerce/ecommerce/ecommerce/extensions/api/serializers.py:418 - Failed to save and publish [course-v1:Org1+CU1+2017]: [Failed to publish commerce data for course-v1:Org1+CU1+20177 to LMS.]
```

It's showing SSL certificate verification failed

Can anyone tell what is the missing configuration settings?

Thanks

Comment: `SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` can happen if you're behind a corporate proxy server that does SSL inspection. Is there a proxy involved on your network?